# How would I run a while loop on a separate thread in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to coroutines in python but I know in lua you would do this to create one

```
coroutine.wrap(function()
 while true do
 end
end)()
```

But I dont know how I would do this python.

I tried using this code which included a function from the slp_coroutine library which didnt work

```
import slp_coroutine
def test():
    while True:
        print("hi")
        time.sleep(3)

r = slp_coroutine.await_coroutine(test())
```

and I also tried this and it also didnt work.

```
async def test():
    while True:
        print("hi")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

asyncio.run(test())
```

Comment: If you just want threads, that is what `threading` is there for. In the Python ecosystem, an explicit "coroutine" is usually used for *very* high concurrency - some hundred to several thousands of tasks.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653/4897206) might help you.